# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory, PHP DEPLOY HEROKU APP

Tags: php, heroku

I'm quite new to deploying PHP applications to Heroku-app, the deployment has been done but once I try to connect any files that require my db.php file, I'm getting this error:

`Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory;`

I've seen many similar posts regarding this matter but what I've found so far only talks about the deployment of Django and PHP Laravel, this application is a simple PHP, javascript, ajax jquery, and HTML. I'm not getting this error when I run it on localhost. Any help would be appreciated!

This is the code for my db.php file.

```
<?php
$host = "us-cdbr-east-04.cleardb.com";
$username = "***********";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "heroku_0730a7da8e4c214";

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');



try{
    $conn =  new PDO("mysql: host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //echo "Connection Made";
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

mysql://b1433bea5b2070:0f5fac81@us-cdbr-east-04.cleardb.com/heroku_0730a7da8e4c214?reconnect=true
?>
```

Comment: Please mask your username and password by ******

Comment: okay sure thing, thanks for the advice!